# Running magellan on pyspark-notebook docker container

Tags: docker, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm running `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` on my Windows 7 machine via docker toolbox.

My start command is:

```
docker run -it --rm --name ds -v /c/Users/<some-folder>:/home/jovyan/work/share -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook start-notebook.sh
```

I'm tying to run the spark package magellan. In the notebook I'm running:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages harsha2010:magellan:1.0.4-s_2.11  pyspark-shell'
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
from magellan.types import Point, Polygon
```

But the module `magellan` can't be found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add more info, like the Dockerfile, it seems you did not install the Magellan module while building the image jupyter/pyspark-notebook

Comment: Anyone have a Docker image with magellan available? This question on SO comes up when searching for that, but not much else useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package Magellan is not installed in that Python of the docker container. You can do this easily inside your Jupyter Notebook. Just execute the following command in a cell:

```
!pip install magellan
```